# How do I resolve a "No Method Error" in my post controller. Devise, Pundit, Blogging app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, pundit

In trying to set-up policies for my practice app. I'm running into a "No Method Error" in my posts controller.

If we zero in on the post controller and my update method here is the code.

```
 def update
authorize @post
respond_to do |format|
if @post.update(post_params)

  format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  #redirect_to @post

else
  render :edit
  format.html { render action: 'edit' }
  format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
```

end

As you can see nothing really special. Just a HTML and JSON rendering of the updated page.

The `authorize` code points to a helper in pundit that looks up the access policies.

Defined in my Admin.rb model i have.

```
def editor?
    self.role == 'editor'
  end
```

The `authorize` code looks up the policy that corresponds to the method name. It looks in the policy class and starts applying the business rules found here. And here is where the problems start.

I get to `def update?
    @admin.editor?
  end`

And it says `undefined method 'editor?' for #<Class:0x007ffb7fa4f6a0>`

The code is on the policy branch on Git : https://github.com/wmuengineer/portfolio/tree/policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lesson learned. Read the docs properly. I needed to use

```
def pundit_user
    current_admin
  end
```

and it works.

Comment: Where did you define this method? I mean, in which controller did you put it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with gem `pundit` but looking at code I can suppose that you define `pundit_user` in a wrong way.

According to [documentation](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#customize-pundit-user) you can customize `pundit_user` as `User.find_by_other_means`. I think this method should return an instance of `User`. You redefine `pundit_user` as [`Admin`](https://github.com/wmuengineer/portfolio/blob/e93405622cdd9ed630065fabdc9eeb09fcc17c59/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L8). I think you should return instance of class `Admin`

Comment: I've added the code 'def pundit_user Admin end' and 'def pundit_user Admin.current_admin end' to the top of the ApplicationPolicy and PostPolicy files.. No luck. Am i adding this code in the right place @gotva ?

Comment: from [documentation](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#customize-pundit-user) `Simply define a method in your controller called pundit_user`. I think you should define it in controller

Comment: Still having the same trouble adding it to the controller. I'm thinking i should just refactor and use the default name.